# How to determine parameters for diminishing return function in a market mix model

Tags: regression, marketing

I am working on a market mix model ad was trying to apply diminishing returns to GRP values for my media activities. I was confused on how to go about it ,i.e how to decide the parameters for the for the diminishing fn ex negative exponential function y = α⋅(1 − e−β⋅x) ; β > 0 has 2 parameters alpha & Beta, there are any number of combinations , what is the approach to finding a reasonable estimate for these values then.